# A proof for Abelian groups are solvable

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

I have seen some proofs for "abelian groups are solvable". Mostly they use induction. However, I came up with my own proof that I have not seen it elsewhere (it might already exist, but I am not aware of it). So I wanted to share my thoughts and see if the proof makes sense:

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Then consider

$$\{1\} \lhd G$$

$\{1\}$ is obviously normal in $G$ and $G/\{1\}$ is isomorphic to $G$, which is abelian.

Does this not prove $G$ is solvable? If so, does this not prove it in general, regardless of the size (i.e. finite vs infinite)?

Comment: Yes, your proof works for all abelian groups. I think it is pretty standard (I guess its standard-ness depends on the precise definition you are working with though). On the other hand, I cannot think of an inductive proof - I mean, what would you induct on to capture *all* abelian groups (as opposed to just, say, finite or finitely generated)? As there are uncountably many abelian groups, standard induction cannot possibly work!

Comment: I see. I think there are multiple definitions of solvable groups. The definition I work with requires $G_i / G_{i+1}$ to be abelian, but some sources require $G_i / G_{i+1}$ to be cyclic https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Solvable_Group

It is unfortunate that mathematical definitions are not universal (in most cases it can be shown different definitions are equivalent)

Comment: You can induct on the size of the group. Here is an example 

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Abelian_Group_is_Solvable

Comment: Working with the stronger cyclic factor definition of solvable, I do not think it is the case that all abelian groups are solvable. It is true though that finite abelian groups would be solvable. Basically, the two alternate definitions of solvable based on abelian/cyclic factors are not equivalent.

Comment: @Josh Your links both assume the group is finite, where induction is fine. (In particular, the definition as cyclic quotients assumes this - I believe this is called "supersolvable", and proofwiki is assuming that a finite supersolvable group is solvable.) If we assume that the groups are infinite then induction has issues.

Comment: @user1729 I see your point. I guess with the definition I am working all abelian groups are solvable, but they might not be "supersolvable".

Comment: Exactly. Any uncountable abelian group will be a counter-example. In summary: proofwiki's definition is incorrect.

Comment: @subrosar: The definition being quoted explicitly restricts to $G$ finite, a hypothesis which is not being reported.

Comment: @Josh: Proofwiki **explicitly** restricts its definition to the context of finite groups. In that context, the two definitions are in fact equivalent.

Comment: @user1729: I would object to the statement that definition if proofwiki is incorrect, given that it is in the context of finite groups. For finite groups, the definition “there is a subnormal series with abelian quotients” is equivalent to “there is a chief series with abelian quotients”.

Comment: Thank you to @ArturoMagidin for correcting me. In the context of finite groups, the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: In general, definitions are context-sensitive (unfortunately!). so it is not about if the definition is incorrect or not, it is about if the proof works well relative to the given definitions relative to its context. Proofwiki's definition does not define solvability for infinite groups. The definition I work with allow infinite abelian groups to be solvable.

Comment: I would agree that you cannot say that this definition is incorrect, but it I would still argue that it is a very bad idea. Why use a definition that only works for finite groups,  instead of the general definition that works for all groups? As we can see from this discussion, it results in confusion. Why not just use the standard (general) definition, and then prove that, in finite solvable groups, there is a subnormal series with cyclic factor groups? (I dislike the various  definitions that are often used for finite nilpotent groups for the same reason.)

Comment: @user1729 A supersolvable group $G$ is one with a normal series (i.e. all subgroups in the series normal in $G$) with cyclic factor groups. It is not true that all finite supersolvable groups are solvable - $A_4$ is a counterexample. Groups with a subnormal series with cyclic factor groups are called polycyclic. They (together with virtually polycyclic groups) form an important class of groups in their own right. So polycyclic is equivalent to solvable for finite groups, but it is a weaker property for infinite groups.

Comment: I agree with Derek's comment. Yes my comment itself was incorrect, but at the time I felt that it was the best way to clear up the OPs confusion.

Comment: @Derek Sunday morning isn't the best time for maths, but I am pretty sure that the proofwiki definition is of supersolvable rather than polycyclic: their definition requires a "composition series", which they define as being a "normal series" rather than subnormal.

Comment: @user1729  Looking at the proofwiki definitions of composition and normal series confirms my opinion  that this is not a helpful or accurate source of information! Yes, a composition series is defined as a maximal normal series, and on the [normal series](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Normal_Series) page we find: "A normal series for  is a sequence of (normal) subgroups of  ..." with the word normal in brackets. That's really clear isn't it! There is some discussion of the terminology further down the page.  (ctd)

Comment: But the standard definitions of supersolvability and polycyclicity are uncontroversial. For supersolvability, the subgroups in the series must all be normal in $G$, so we get small examples like $A_4$ that are solvable/polycyclic but not supersovable.

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay mea culpa. I just copied the definition from "Elements of Abstract Algebra" by Allan Clark which is just some random textbook I found in a shop somewhere ages ago. I personally wouldn't be able to tell a solvable group from a supersolvable group if they clubbed together and kicked me on the behind. I know, everybody everywhere knows that ProofWiki is the most rubbish website in the history of the cosmos and it needs to be deleted. Or perhaps contributed to by people who know what's what. Or just denounced. I gave up caring for lent.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question: yes, your proof is fine.

However, the comments uncovered some issues with proofwiki which are worth going into. There are 3 relevant definitions.

1. A group $G$ is *solvable* if there exists a chain of subgroups $\{1\}=G_1\leq G_2\leq\ldots \leq G_n=G$ such that $G_i\lhd G_{i+1}$ and $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian.
2. A group $G$ is *polycyclic* if there exists a chain of subgroups $\{1\}=G_1\leq G_2\leq\ldots \leq G_n=G$ such that $G_i\lhd G_{i+1}$ and $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is cyclic.
3. A group $G$ is *supersolvable* if there exists a chain of subgroups $\{1\}=G_1\leq G_2\leq\ldots \leq G_n=G$ such that $G_i\lhd G$ and $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is cyclic.

The differences are that in (2) and (3) we require the quotients to be cyclic rather than just abelian, and in (3) we require the $G_i$ to be normal in $G$ (so we have a "normal series" rather than just a "subnormal series").

Clearly we have supersolvable$\subset$polycyclic$\subset$solvable. For finite groups, one can prove that polycyclic$=$solvable, which is presumably what proofwiki is aiming for. The group $A_4$ is easily seen to be solvable (as it's derived subgroup is the Klein $4$-group, which is abelian), but is *not* supersolvable as no non-trivial cyclic subgroup is normal.

[Proofwiki's definition of "solvable"](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Solvable_Group) actually corresponds to supersolvable, and therefore is **incorrect** as these two classes of groups are different, even if we only consider finite groups. (To be precise: their definition states $G$ "has a composition series in which each factor is a cyclic group", while they define a composition series to be a specific kind of *normal*, rather than subnormal, series.)